# Auction type Countdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have been trying for days so I finally thought I should ask. Below I will post what I have, any direct solutions would be great. I will try to be as detailed as possible.

**What I need to create?**

An Auction type countdown with interaction with MySQL to retrieve the End Time of the Item in question. I will also be using Javascript to get a live countdown animation. It needs to use the Servers Time and not the users time on thier computer which it does not seem to be working.

**File Types Used**

PHP, Javascript, MySQL

**Special Notes**

I must also ensure that the time is from the server and not the target computer.  If there is a better way to do what I am trying please let me know. I have done lots of research and still can not get this to work.

**File Names**

```
index.php           - Main File
db.php              - Connection to DB          - within "system" folder
functions.php       - Contains all functions.   - within "system" folder
```

**DataBase Info**

```
Table Name: time 
Fields : id, name, end_time
```

Note on DataBase : "end_time" is a TimeStamp

**index.php**

```
 <?
   // Calls the DB for Connection
   include("system/db.php"); 
   // Calls all Functions
   include("system/functions.php"); 
 ?>

 <!-- Loads the actual Countdown -->
  <div id="countdowncontainer"></div>
 <br />

 <?
 // This Part loads the "end_date" so the countdown can stop.
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   $id_num = "1";
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = '$id_num'");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
         $end_time = $row['end_date'];   // 2013-12-11 00:00:00
         $end_time = $end_time ;
   }
 ?>


  <!-- The script below loads the data from the server in this format : 
  2013-12-11 00:00:00 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var futuredate=new cdtime("countdowncontainer", "<? echo $end_time; ?>")
         futuredate.displaycountdown("days", formatresults)

    </script>
```

The following file is the function file. This is where I assume I need to change or do something so that it can load the server time and not the local time.

**functions.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cdtime(container, targetdate) {
        if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container)) return
        this.container = document.getElementById(container)
        this.currentTime = new Date()
        this.targetdate = new Date(targetdate)
        this.timesup = false
        this.updateTime()
    }

    cdtime.prototype.updateTime = function () {
        var thisobj = this
        this.currentTime.setSeconds(this.currentTime.getSeconds() + 1)
        setTimeout(function () {
            thisobj.updateTime()
        }, 1000) //update time every second
    }

    cdtime.prototype.displaycountdown = function (baseunit, functionref) {
        this.baseunit = baseunit
        this.formatresults = functionref
        this.showresults()
    }

    cdtime.prototype.showresults = function () {
        var thisobj = this


        var timediff = (this.targetdate - this.currentTime) / 1000 //difference btw target date and                                                                 current date, in seconds
        if (timediff < 0) { //if time is up
            this.timesup = true
            this.container.innerHTML = this.formatresults()
            return
        }
        var oneMinute = 60 //minute unit in seconds
        var oneHour = 60 * 60 //hour unit in seconds
        var oneDay = 60 * 60 * 24 //day unit in seconds
        var dayfield = Math.floor(timediff / oneDay)
        var hourfield = Math.floor((timediff - dayfield * oneDay) / oneHour)
        var minutefield = Math.floor((timediff - dayfield * oneDay - hourfield * oneHour) / oneMinute)
        var secondfield = Math.floor((timediff - dayfield * oneDay - hourfield * oneHour - minutefield * oneMinute))
        if (this.baseunit == "hours") { //if base unit is hours, set "hourfield" to be topmost  level
            hourfield = dayfield * 24 + hourfield
            dayfield = "n/a"
        } else if (this.baseunit == "minutes") { //if base unit is minutes, set "minutefield" to be    topmost level
            minutefield = dayfield * 24 * 60 + hourfield * 60 + minutefield
            dayfield = hourfield = "n/a"
        } else if (this.baseunit == "seconds") { //if base unit is seconds, set "secondfield" to be  topmost level
            var secondfield = timediff
            dayfield = hourfield = minutefield = "n/a"
        }
        this.container.innerHTML = this.formatresults(dayfield, hourfield, minutefield, secondfield)
        setTimeout(function () {
            thisobj.showresults()
        }, 1000) //update results every second
    }




    function formatresults() {
        if (this.timesup == false) { //if target date/time not yet met
            var displaystring = arguments[0] + " days " + arguments[1] + " hours " + arguments[2] + " minutes     " + arguments[3] + " seconds <b>left until Target Date </b>"
        } else { //else if target date/time met
            var displaystring = "<? $test2 = "
            Test Is a Success ";?><b><? echo $test2; ?></b>"
        }
        return displaystring
    }
</script>
```

Now this works fine to a point. However, If i change my local time I can cheat around it rather than the time being the server time as that cant be changed.

*What am I missing?*

Comment: `this.currentTime=new Date()` use local date, because it's executed client-side. You should get the current timestamp in PHP and give it to your `cdtime` function : then the local date would never be used. **EDIT** : Why there is no `;` in your code ?

Comment: It would probably be better to get how long (in seconds) is left until the countdown is done, then pass this to Javascript and set the time based on how long is left. This keeps it local for the user and makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me at mysql_

Comment: How would I add the current timestamp to the cdtime function?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a much better approach to retrieve the counter length in Milliseconds (or Seconds) and then pass this to your javascript function to create the `targetdate`. That way the countdown is relative to the user. For example :

> 1. The user lives in a time zone +5 hours from your server
> 2. Your Countdown will finish at say 17:00 04/12/2013 (for the Server)
> 3. For the actual user, the countdown will finish at 22:00 04/12/2013.
>
> (If you do not keep it local to the user, timings will be incorrect and can easily start to confuse your users.)

Example of adding Milliseconds to a Date (This adds 5 hours to the Javascript date) :

```
var targetdate=new Date(currentTime.getTime() + 18000000);
```

Example to get Time Difference (Using Javascript) :

```
// PHP
//Get current date
$currdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_time = $row['end_date'];   // 2013-12-11 00:00:00
$end_time = $end_time;

// Javascript
//Pass current date to the Javascript function
var futuredate=new cdtime("countdowncontainer", "<? echo $currdate; ?>", "<? echo $end_time; ?>")

function cdtime(container, currentdate, targetdate) {
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container)) return
    this.container = document.getElementById(container)
    this.currentTime = new Date()
    //Creates temp date variables
    var curDate = new Date(currentdate);
    var endDate = new Date(targetdate);
    //Gets time Difference in Milliseconds
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - curDate.getTime();
    //Sets targetdate to be the current date + the difference
    this.targetdate = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + diff)
    this.timesup = false
    this.updateTime()
}
```

Comment: Love that Idea, now just have to find out how to do that. :/

Comment: @user3063070 - See my updated answer for an example of doing this in Javascript. I get the current date from PHP and pass it to the javascript function to get the difference in Milliseconds. (You could do this in PHP and then pass the Milliseconds but the examples I found were quite large)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
   this.currentTime=new Date()
```

You are using the local client date as the "current" date.  Instead you should pass it in much like you do with the target date.

E.g. Like this

```
   (php)
   $current_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

   (javascript)
   var futuredate = new cdtime( "countdowncontainer", "<? echo $current_time; ?>", "<? echo $end_time; ?>")
```

and

```
   function cdtime(container, currentdate, targetdate) {
     ...
     this.currentdate=new Date(currentdate)
```

Having done that you can have the clock tick with your timeout functions.

However, this will cause the time to creep a little (notice how it does that on eBay sometimes).

The way round that is, every now and again, to ask the server for the time again. and reset 'currentTime'.  You can do that by implementing a simple service with PHP that returns the time - probably as JSON, and then call it with AJAX.

Comment: How would I pass it like I did on the target date? Idea's?

Comment: Yep, exactly the same, just using the output of `date` - answer updated